# How to change the style of react bootstrap split button

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

How to change the style of react bootstrap split button

I have used react bootstrap split button as below

```
   <ButtonToolbar>
    <SplitButton bsStyle="primary" title="Right dropup" 
    dropup pullRight id="split-button-dropup-pull-right">
    <MenuItem eventKey="1">Action</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem eventKey="2">Another action</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem eventKey="3">Something else 
      here</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem divider />
    <MenuItem eventKey="4">Separated link</MenuItem>
  </SplitButton>
</ButtonToolbar>
```

);

I want to apply some other color and style to the button .
I tried using className but it applies to only button part not arrow (caret) part

So how can i do this?

Comment: What className did you apply? And what styling does it have?

Comment: Classes : Btn btn-info btn-fill

Comment: You may just override one of existing bsStyles with your styles

Answer (score 0):

The docs say

> As with `DropdownButton`, `SplitButton` is provided as **convenience** component.

Source: https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/docs/components/dropdowns/#split-button-dropdowns

Your solution should be (inconvenient):

```
<Dropdown as={ButtonGroup}>
  <Button variant="primary">Right dropup</Button>
  <DropdownToggle split>
    <i className="fa fa-caret-down text-danger"></i>
  </DropdownToggle>
  <DropdownMenu>
    <DropdownItem href="#">...</DropdownItem>
    <DropdownItem href="#">...</DropdownItem>
  </DropdownMenu>
</Dropdown>
```